# By using FileAppender how to clear my previous data and write newly data?

Tags: java, log4j

The code is as follows:

```
public class Client {

static Logger l = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {      

  Layout l1 = new SimpleLayout();
  Appender a;

  try
  {
  a = new FileAppender(l1,"my.txt", false);

  l.addAppender(a);
  } 
  catch(Exception e) {}      

  l.fatal("This is the error message..");
  System.out.println("Your logic executed successfully....");
  }
}
/*My Properties file*/
log4j.rootLogger = WARN,abc
log4j.appender.abc = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.abc.file = my111.txt
log4j.appender.abc.layout = org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
```

By using false in FileAppender(l1,"my.txt", false);
I got but if i use log4j.properties file how can I achieve this
Properties file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
log4j.appender.<your appender>.Append=false
```

Comment: Thank u for your quick reply but .. still it's append to the old data